# Scintilla 'Before change' notification

Tags: notifications, onchange, scintilla

I need to do certain processing when a Scintilla editor first becomes 'dirty' *before* the document actually changes.

The `SCN_SAVEPOINTLEFT` notification seems like the obvious candidate, but unfortunately this is fired *after* the change that made the document dirty has occurred.

Looking through the other available notifications, `SCN_MODIFIED` also is fired *after* the change has happened (and the same is true of `SCEN_CHANGE` of course).

The best I can think of is to start macro recording in response to `SCN_SAVEPOINTREACHED` (i.e. when the document is saved or all changes are undone). Then when I detect the first change with `SCN_MODIFIED`, I stop recording, undo all changes until I get back to the save point, perform my custom processing (which happens to be modifying a date field in the document), then replay the recorded macros to restore the undone changes.

This seems horribly convoluted. Is there an easier way? (Maybe it would be simpler to create my own custom version of Scintilla with a SCN_BEFORECHANGE notification, but I'd prefer to avoid creating a fork. And a cursory glance through the source suggests that there are a great many points from where this notification would have to be sent, making it easy to miss some.)

---

Update: The real requirement was that when the user executes 'Undo' after first modifying the document, the 'automatic' edit and the user's first edit are not in the wrong order in the undo buffer. The simplest solution turned out to be, not to force the automatic update to be first, but to coalesce these two actions into a single undo action using `SCI_BEGINUNDOACTION`/`SCI_ENDUNDOACTION`. See my comment below on how I did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SCN_MODIFIED](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCN_MODIFIED) notification *does* seem to fit your spec. The `modificationType` field provides information about what has been done, including:

> ```
> SC_MOD_BEFOREINSERT 0x400 Text is about to be inserted into the document.
> SC_MOD_BEFOREDELETE 0x800 Text is about to be deleted from the document.
> ```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: In fact due to it not being permitted to change the text in the editor inside a `SCN_MODIFIED` handler, I've ended up with the following solution: 1. In response to `SCN_SAVEPOINTREACHED` set a flag and send `SCI_BEGINUNDOACTION`. 2. In response to `SCN_MODIFIED` with the flag set post self a custom message. 3. In the custom message handler modify the editor and then send `SCI_ENDUNDOACTION`. This coalesces the automatic modification with the user's first modification, so the two actions don't appear in the wrong order when undone. This effectively meets my requirements.